# Insert two form fields together in loop

Tags: php, forms

I have two form fields "First name" and "Last name" I can also clone the two fields to add more users on one submit.
I want each record to have it's own ID once inserted into the database. However I can't seen to get it to insert two values at once in a loop.

My form fields are

```
 <input type="text" name="firstname_0" size="35" value="" />
 <input type="text" name="lastname_0" size="35" value="" />
```

The name auto increments every time I want to add another user firstname_1, lastname_1 etc...

I would like to add 1 or unlimited users in one form submit.

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried using a foreach() and while but can't get the concept.

Comment: Please include the SQL query you're using to insert. The proper syntax is `INSERT INTO tablename (field1, field2...) VALUES (record1_value1, record1_value2), (record2_value1, record2_value2)...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrays in the inputs' name attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="users[0]['firstname']" size="35" value="" />
<input type="text" name="users[0]['lastname']" size="35" value="" />

<input type="text" name="users[1]['firstname']" size="35" value="" />
<input type="text" name="users[1]['lastname']" size="35" value="" />
```

And then:

```
foreach ($_POST['users'] as $user) {
}
```

Comment: while(isset($_POST['firstname_'.$i]))
         {
           $firstname = $_POST['firstname_'.$i];
           $lastname = $_POST['lastname_'.$i];

          // I would like to insert firstname and lastname in one query then move on to next.

     

           $i++; 
        }

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the very helpful guidance Samy!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to change your input fields with arrays

```
<input type="text" name="firstname[0]" size="35" value="" />
<input type="text" name="lastname[0]" size="35" value="" />
```

And you keep adding inputs increasing its key

```
<input type="text" name="firstname[1]" size="35" value="" />
<input type="text" name="lastname[1]" size="35" value="" />
......
<input type="text" name="firstname[2]" size="35" value="" />
<input type="text" name="lastname[2]" size="35" value="" />
```

Then on your PHP you can proccess the data easily.

```
$firstName = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastName  = $_POST['lastname'];
.... do some checks ....

foreach ($firstName as $key => $name)
{
     insert_to_db($name, $lastName[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="user[][firstname]" size="35" value="" />
<input type="text" name="user[][lastname]" size="35" value="" />
```

use your input like this..

than print_r($_POST['user']);
you will see what happend..

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="firstname[]" size="35" value="Waqar" />
<input type="text" name="lastname[]" size="35" value="Alamgir" />


<input type="text" name="firstname[]" size="35" value="Natasha" />
<input type="text" name="lastname[]" size="35" value="Milla" />
```